# Using a Sick laser with Matlab in Windows

Tags: mobile-robot, localization

Is there a Matlab toolbox available to use [Sick lasers](http://www.sick.com/us/en-us/home/products/product_portfolio/laser_measurement_systems/Pages/indoor_laser_measurement_technology.aspx) in Windows?

I found [one toolbox for Matlab in GNU/Linux](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sicktoolbox/).  Is there another way to use Sick laser via Matlab in Windows?

Comment: If all fails, you can write your own using mex http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating-c-c-and-fortran-programs-to-be-callable-from-matlab-mex-files.html basically, get the example code from sick, see how they init the device and grab data from it. Write the stuff in mex to output the data in Matlab friendly format

Comment: SICK laser scanners send their data over a pretty simple serial interface.  I'm sure you can find the API easily.  Then it is just a matter of getting serial data in Matlab, which is a question for a different site.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with [the Sick LIDAR Matlab/C++ Toolbox](http://sicktoolbox.sourceforge.net/), its pretty easy to use and does the job very well.

Comment: it is only for linux,finally i found same tool box ported to windows by one of the faculty.thanks for response.

Comment: Your welcome, happy you solved your problem, you seem like you'll be doing some awesome stuff with your SICK :D

Comment: from your comment it seems that you got a ported version of the Sick LIDAR Matlab/C++ Toolbox.
I tried porting the toolbox myself with no success. Would it be possible to get the Windows Version from you?

Comment: Any chance you could post your own answer with a link to the windows version you found please @bvbdort , thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it was not online. It was from deportment.

Comment: Is that the toolbox that you discuss above support SICK Tim 561?

Comment: Terry - (1) Please don't use an *answer* as a place to ask a question, you can ask your own, and (2) if you follow the link and read the documentation it clearly states that the only two families explicitly supported are the LMS200 and LD (as in LD-LRS). The TiM is not explicitly supported.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.